# Accessing System app data from User context application (C#, Console App)

Tags: c#, windows, service, console

I'm having a console application and a service. When trying to access app data from Service, it's something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\
```

But when accessing it from console application, it's like this:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\
```

I understand why this happens. However, is there a way to access system app data (like service) from console application?

Comment: No because of NTFS permissions - and with good reasons as this would be an incredible security hole.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yeah, sounds like something that could cause some security issues. However, I was just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Is this for testing? You can run interactively as SYSTEM via `psexec -sid <command>`.